# SocialMedia module is not replacing [socialmedia:sm-twitter_username] when sharing to Twitter

Tags: 7, tokens

When I use the SocialMedia Twitter button, it opens a new window which displays:

[image]

As you can see, the [socialmedia:sm-twitter_username] token is not being replaced.

In the user's profile, there is a tab (which I believe was added by this module) called "Social Profiles" He has entered his Twitter username :

[image]

Can anyone tell me why this token isn't being picked up ?

Comment: Some things you can try: Have you installed all the modules? Did you run the setup wizard in the module configuration page? Have you tried to clear your cache? Maybe there are other modules interfering with it? I installed the module on a clean Drupal install and I was able to share a link with my twitter handle correctly printed in the post.

Comment: Hi Ismail, thanks.  I tried all the above and still having the problem - I think there must be another module interfering with it, but not sure how I would track that down?  In the meantime, thankfully my client only ever wants to see the same twitter handle being used, so I've hardcoded it into the module - I know, terrible practice, but it gets the job done and I can move onto the next issue